# ¿Cómo puedo recoger los datos que se encuentran en un input de un tr específico?

Tags: jquery, laravel, php7

Estoy tratando de recoger unos datos en una tabla dinámica al hacer click en su correspondiente botón por medio de JQuery. Este es el código del HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Título</th>
    <th>Autor</th>
    <th>Fecha creación</th>
    <th>Género Literario</th>
    <th>Género Artístico</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
    </thead>
    {{$i=0}}
    @foreach($libros as $lib)
        <tr id="fila1{{$i}}">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="{{$lib->lib_titulo}}" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">{{$lib->lib_titulo}}</td>
            <td>{{$lib->autor}}</td>
            <td>{{$lib->lib_fecha_creacion}}</td>
            <td>{{$lib->generoliterario}}</td>
            <td>{{$lib->generoartistico}}</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="{{$lib->lib_precio}}"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$lib->id_libro}}" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver({{$lib->id_libro}})" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{$i++}}
    @endforeach
```

Y este el código que yo he generado por medio de JQuery que me funcionaría si fueran id pero como referencio a los campos por medio de class en vez de id al ser dinámico no me funciona...

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn_add').click(function(){

                agregar();
            })
        });
function agregar()
        {
            idlibro=$(".lped_libro_id").val();
            libro=$(".lped_lib_titulo").val();
            cantidad=$(".lped_unidades").val();
            pvp=$(".lped_pvp").val();


            if(idlibro!="" && cantidad!="" && cantidad>0 && libro!="")
            {
                subtotal[i]=(cantidad*pvp*0.18);
                total=total+subtotal[i];

                var fila='<tr class="selected" id="fila' + i+ '">' +
                    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="eliminar('+i+');">X</button></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name="ped_no[]" value="'+ no +'">'+ no + '</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="hidden" name="idlibro[]" value="'+ idlibro +'">'+ libro + '</td>'+
                        '<input type="hidden" name="libro[]" value="'+libro+ '">'+
                    '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+ cantidad +'">'+ cantidad + '</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="number" name="pvp[]" value="'+ pvp +'">'+ pvp + '</td>'+
                    '<td><input type="number" name="iva[]" value="'+ 0.18 +'">'+ 18% + '</td>'+
                    '<td>' + subtotal[i] + '</td>'+
                    '</tr>';
                no++;

                limpiar();
                $("#total").html(total + " €");
                evaluar();
                $("#detalles").append(fila);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error al ingresar detalle de ingreso");
            }
        } el código aquí
```

¿Podría alguien decirme cual es el código jquery para coger los datos de los input de la tr seleccionada?

Este es el código que se genera:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Título</th>
    <th>Autor</th>
    <th>Fecha creación</th>
    <th>Género Literario</th>
    <th>Género Artístico</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
    </thead>
                <tr id="5">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="El señor de los anillos" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">El señor de los anillos</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>2018-01-29</td>
            <td>Impresionismo</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="12.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="5" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(5)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr id="3">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="El principito" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">El principito</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>2018-01-29</td>
            <td>Impresionismo</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="10.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="3" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(3)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr id="2">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="Persiles y segismunda" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">Persiles y segismunda</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>2018-01-26</td>
            <td>Esperpento</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="5.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(2)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr id="1">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="luces de bohemia" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">luces de bohemia</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>1924-07-26</td>
            <td>Esperpento</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="10.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(1)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Hola María. Puedes poner también el HTML generado en la web? Asi podemos ver como queda tras la generación dinámica y poder trastear con jQuery. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Claro, faltaría más, lo acabo de añadir. Un saludo!

Comment: Veo que en el HTML generado te sobran dos `}}` tras la propiedad `value`. Respecto a tu pregunta,  ¿quieres que al hacer click en el boton recoja los datos de la fila seleccionada? ¿Has probado a añadir una clase `selected` cuando hagas click en ella y asi detectar cual es desde jQuery?

Comment: Exáctamente, quiero que recoja los datos de los input de la fila seleccionada. ¿Con selected te refieres a esta línea? $(this).addClass('selected'); La he probado pero no hace nada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente es muy sencillo, ya que cada `tr` tiene un id. Lo que tienes que pedir a jquery es el valor del `input` con el `name` dado que esté en un `td` que sea hijo de del elemento con el `id` dado. Eso, traducido a *CSS query* es lo siguiente:

```
'#id_de_la_fila > td > input[name=nombre_del_input]'

function valor(idTr,inputName) {
  return $('#'+idTr+' > td > input[name='+inputName+']').val();
}
```

Aquí lo tienes funcionando con tu tabla:

```js
function valor(idTr,inputName) {
      return $('#'+idTr+' > td > input[name='+inputName+']').val();
}


$('tr').on('click',function () {
  let id=$(this).attr('id');
  console.log('Libro seleccionado:', valor(id,'lped_lib_titulo'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Título</th>
    <th>Autor</th>
    <th>Fecha creación</th>
    <th>Género Literario</th>
    <th>Género Artístico</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
    </thead>
                <tr id="5">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="El señor de los anillos" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">El señor de los anillos</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>2018-01-29</td>
            <td>Impresionismo</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="12.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="5" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(5)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr id="3">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="El principito" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">El principito</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>2018-01-29</td>
            <td>Impresionismo</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="10.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="3" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(3)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr id="2">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="Persiles y segismunda" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">Persiles y segismunda</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>2018-01-26</td>
            <td>Esperpento</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="5.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(2)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr id="1">
            <td><input type="hidden" value="luces de bohemia" name="lped_lib_titulo" class="lped_lib_titulo">luces de bohemia</td>
            <td>valleinclán</td>
            <td>1924-07-26</td>
            <td>Esperpento</td>
            <td>Renacimiento</td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="lped_unidades" class="lped_unidades"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="10.00"}} disabled name="lped_pvp" class="lped_pvp">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="lped_libro_id" class="lped_libro_id"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_add" onclick="ver(1)" >Añadir</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```